# I got error on column with identity(1,1)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Sql developer gives an error of:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, for next table :

```
create table customer (
    CUSTOMER_ID number identity (1,1) not null,
    CUSTOMER_PHONE char(13) not null
);
```

Also the 'identity is red underlined, have no idea why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper syntax for Oracle 12c and newer:

```
create table customer ( 
  CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  CUSTOMER_PHONE char(13) not null 
);

-- explicit start and increment
create table customer ( 
  CUSTOMER_ID  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  CUSTOMER_PHONE char(13) not null 
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7561fd0d6869e229fe0760e87e0ba4c4)**

Comment: That is weird, I was google for find some answer, and most of reponse was that one from my code.

Thank you, Lukasz

Comment: @don'tknownothing The syntax you posted is for Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: Oh my.. that's why I'm new in SQL :)))

Comment: @don'tknownothing No worries :) Everyone started from scratch